# Probleme update Ubuntu Package

Tags: 12.04, package-management

i've created a remote server on Amazon Cloud, when i connect into the VM, and type "sudo apt-get update" i get:

[image]

Where is the problem here ? i didn't inderstand any thing !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ubuntu installation is not connected to the internet. If it is running in a VM, make sure that the VM software is set to use `Bridge Mode`, or `NAT`, alternatively, NOT host-only. Otherwise, make sure your router supports DHCP or specify an IP address for your Ubuntu installation by hand.

Comment: After fews days, i release that u're right, and there is a problem of network connection, in fact i'm in network connected to another network via a VPN, and that waht makes problems if i want to connect to internet, so have you and idea how can i resolve this problem ? Thank's

Comment: @user1959686, is the VPN set on the host computer, or inside the virtual machine?

Comment: Thank you very much, we resolved the problem in my company, we created a server with 2 interfaces, private and public